# PHP Array - Multi Dimension into table split

Tags: php, arrays

Dumb question.  Below is my array.  I got the first dimension to return to a table with a foreach loop, how do I iterate the 'work_order_status' part of the array to be able to set it into a table value?

```
Array
    (
        [transaction_id] => 2014102413362746N1SSCSYY9PFSUS85-0
        [response_code] => 200
        [work_order] => 151262
        [percent_complete] => 100
        [duplicate_records] => 0
        [work_order_status] => Array
            (
                [record] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [record_count] => 1590
                                [percent_of_total] => 40.52
                                [description] => Successful delivery
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [record_count] => 2
                                [percent_of_total] => .05
                                [description] => Invalid Number - too short
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [record_count] => 2
                                [percent_of_total] => .05
                                [description] => Invalid Number - Illegal NPA-NXX
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [record_count] => 2
                                [percent_of_total] => .05
                                [description] => Invalid Number - NULL submission
                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [record_count] => 1
                                [percent_of_total] => .03
                                [description] => Invalid Number - Not a dialable number
                            )

                        [5] => Array
                            (
                                [record_count] => 996
                                [percent_of_total] => 25.38
                                [description] => Invalid Request - not a WIRELESS number
                            )

                        [6] => Array
                            (
                                [record_count] => 867
                                [percent_of_total] => 22.09
                                [description] => Max Account Retries Exceeded
                            )

                        [7] => Array
                            (
                                [record_count] => 18
                                [percent_of_total] => .46
                                [description] => Voicemail delivery unconfirmed
                            )

                        [8] => Array
                            (
                                [record_count] => 3
                                [percent_of_total] => .08
                                [description] => Voicemail played for 0 seconds
                            )

                        [9] => Array
                            (
                                [record_count] => 341
                                [percent_of_total] => 8.69
                                [description] => Voicemail played for less than message length.
                            )

                        [10] => Array
                            (
                                [record_count] => 18
                                [percent_of_total] => .46
                                [description] => No Answer
                            )

                        [11] => Array
                            (
                                [record_count] => 76
                                [percent_of_total] => 1.94
                                [description] => Network Disconnect (FEHU)
                            )

                        [12] => Array
                            (
                                [record_count] => 8
                                [percent_of_total] => .2
                                [description] => Duplicate Records
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

Comment: `foreach($array['work_order_status'] as $something) {}`

Comment: a second `foreach` loop ? provide what you have done, and what you would like your table to look like so we can help further

Comment: You have to iterate over the first array with a loop, and inside that loop, iterate again over the work_order_status array.

Comment: We don't allow dumb questions here.

Comment: I just want to return the contents of 'record' key into its own table, nothing more.  Problem with testing this is the API I am connecting to doesn't let me query more than once every 5 minutes so my responses are going to slow as I am working on other stuff.  Biggest problem is I am normally used to referring to the key position as [0] or [1] and in this case it's returning the first byte each time.  I have not worked with multidimension arrays before in php obviously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a foreach loop such as:

```
foreach($array['work_order_status'] as $value) {
    //some code here
}
```

or if the `['record']` part of the array is actually the one you wanted to iterate over then you could do something like this:

```
foreach($array['work_order_status']['record'] as $value) {
    //some code here
}
```

Edit after comments:

```
foreach ($xml2['work_order_status']['record'] as $value)  {  
    echo "<td>" . $xml2 . "</td>" . 
    "<td>" . $value['record_count'] . "</td>" .
    "<td>" . $value['percent_of_total'] . "</td>" . 
    "<td>" . $value['description'] . "</td><tr>";
}
```

Comment: Problem with attempting this is the API I am returning these results limits me to one query/5 minutes and oops enter saves the reply.  `foreach ($xml2['work_order_status'] as $value) {
echo "<td>" . $xml2 . "</td><td>" . $value . "</td><tr>";
}`

Comment: You would have to elaborate a bit more in order for me to be of any help to you.

Comment: Yep sorry.  I want to return record_count, percent_of_total, and description of every 'record' array element.  The output comes in as XML and I am using json_decode/json_encode to put it into an array, I just want to build a <td> of each 'record' array element instead of displaying it in print_r format.  `$data = curl_exec($ch);  
$xml2 = json_decode( json_encode(simplexml_load_string($data)) , 1); foreach ($xml2['work_order_status']['record'] as $key =>$value) {
echo "<td>" . $xml2 . "</td><td>" . $value . "</td><tr>";
}` is returning 'Array' over and over now at least.

Comment: @Alex Using that foreach loop your keys are 1,2,3,... and your values are arrays containing `[record_count]`,`[percent_of_total]`, and `[description]`. So if you change your foreach loop to something like this it should work as you want it to: `foreach ($xml2['work_order_status']['record'] as $key =>$value) { echo "<td>" . $xml2 . "</td><td>" . $value['record_count'] . "</td><tr>" . "<td>" . $xml2 . "</td><td>" . $value['percent_of_total'] . "</td><tr>" . "<td>" . $xml2 . "</td><td>" . $value['description'] . "</td><tr>"; }` This way you output 3 rows with the desired values on each iteration.

Comment: Thanks, I wil lgive that a try in about 5 minutes :)

Comment: @Greenz that did it, thank you :) My problem was trying $value[0] was returning the 0 position of the string and I never thought to refer to the actual key :(

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($xml2['work_order_status']['record'] as $key =>$value) { 
    echo "<td>" . $xml2 . "</td><td>" . $value['record_count'] . "</td><tr>" . "<td>" . $xml2 . "</td><td>" . $value['percent_of_total'] . "</td><tr>" . "<td>" . $xml2 . "</td><td>" . $value['description'] . "</td><tr>";
     }
```